# Check List of List size in rendered

Tags: visualforce, rendered

I have a List of List of account declared in controller like this:

```
public List<List<Account>> listofListOfAccount {get; set;}
```

Now I want to determine size of 1st list item in the List of List from VisualForce rendered.

I am trying do something like this, but this is not working:

```
<apex:messages rendered="{!listofListOfAccount[0].size>100}" layout="table"></apex:messages>
```

Please advice.

Edit: Added VF/Controller code

VF:

```
<apex:page controller="RendererListofListOfAccount" >
  {! listofListOfAccount.size} 
  <apex:messages rendered="{!AND(listofListOfAccount.size>0, listofListOfAccount[0].size>100)}" layout="table"></apex:messages>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class RendererListofListOfAccount {
    public List<List<Account>> listofListOfAccount {get; set;}
    public RendererListofListOfAccount() {
        listofListOfAccount = new List<List<Account>>();
        List<Account> acLst = [select id, name from account limit 2];
        listofListOfAccount.add(acLst);
         acLst = [select id, name from account limit 1];
        listofListOfAccount.add(acLst);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"?  Try outputing the value directly into the page text, like `{!listofListOfAccount[0].size}`, to see what's being compared.  Seems likely that listofListOfAccount may not be correctly populated.  You might also output `{!listofListOfAccount.size}` to confirm the top-level list as well.

Comment: @JasonClark: For {!listofListOfAccount.size} = 0..but {!listofListOfAccount[0].size} results an error:
`Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Number, received Text
Error is in expression '{!listofListOfAccount[0].size}' in component <apex:page> in page rendererlistoflistofaccount`

Comment: As my List contains only one record. So, this code is working fine for me:

`<apex:repeat value="{!listofListOfAccount}" var="listofAccount">

        <apex:messages rendered="{!listofAccount.size >= 0}" layout="table"></apex:messages> 
    </apex:repeat>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your sublist to a variable and then access the size of the new variable.

Controller:

```
public class testPageController {
    public List<List<String>> listoflistofstrings {get; set;}

    public testPageController() {
        listoflistofstrings = new List<List<String>>();

        for(Integer x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            listoflistofstrings.add(new List<String>());

            for(Integer y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
                listoflistofstrings[x].add(string.valueOf(y));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="testPageController">
    <apex:variable value="{!listoflistofstrings[0]}" var="subList"/>
    {!AND(listoflistofstrings.size > 0, subList.size > 3)}
</apex:page>
```

My best guess as to why it doesn't work the way you did it is because the formula engine doesn't have as robust of a typecasting engine as what is built into the apex:variable component. The formula probably only checks basic types such as string, int, date/time, etc and ends up casting it as a generic object where as the apex:variable component also checks more complex types such as lists and maps and type casts it correctly.

Comment: Wow! Your suggestion worked! I added this line in VF `<apex:variable value="{!listofListOfAccount[0]}" var="listofAc"/>` and then compared `listofAc.size>100` in rendered. Can you please explain the logic why it was not working with previous logic, if possible. Anyway I am choosing it as best answer..

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is correct.  As I noted in my comment, a good next step is to add the expression you are trying to debug directly to the page output, like so:

```
<p>list of List[0] size:  {!listofListOfAccount[0].size}</p>
```

If the top level list is empty, you will receive an error; you can also check the top level list directly:

```
<p>list of List size:  {!listofListOfAccount.size}</p>
```

Since you noted in your comment that this returns 0, the issue is not in your `rendered` property formula, but in your apex controller; `listofListOfAccount` is an empty list when the page is rendered.  Take a look at where in your controller this is populated, and make sure that the code will be executed.  You may also need to add debugging output (`system.debug(...)`) to your controller to help you determine what's happening there, for example if the `list<list<account>>` is being populated by a query, it may not be returning anything.

Also:  if you are getting errors when the list is empty without the extra output (due to the expression in `rendered`), you can change the formula to check the list size before checking element 0:

```
<apex:messages rendered="{!AND(listofListOfAccount>0, listofListOfAccount[0].size>100)}" layout="table"></apex:messages>
```

This way, if the top-level list is empty, the check of `[0]` will never happen because `AND()` is a short-circuit operation (i.e., if the first item is false, it need not check the second item).

Comment: If I provide only `{!listofListOfAccount.size}` in code, it results 2. But if add `<apex:messages rendered="{!AND(listofListOfAccount.size>0, listofListOfAccount[0].size>100)}" layout="table"></apex:messages>` it results an error as `Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Number, received Text
Error is in expression '{!AND(listofListOfAccount.size>0, listofListOfAccount[0].size>100)}' in component <apex:messages> in page rendererlistoflistofaccount`
I have added VF/Controller code sample in the question for your reference.

Comment: @Robi my answer has an example of how to fix the "Incorrect parameter type for subscript" error